# VB.Net Hide a process from task manager

Tags: .net, vb.net, taskmanager

I'm trying to hide a process from task manager. Is it possible ? Btw. it isn't a malware program or something else.

Answer (score 6):

Completely **hiding away a running process is not possible**. And for what it's worth: it's a *great* thing it ain't. I can't imagine being a system administrator and not being allowed to see what processes are running on my system.

It would probably be better if you explained your requirements in greater details. Whatever you need hiding the process for there *has* to be a better solution.